# Cannot render Three js objects added to the scene within a jQuery $.get request function

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm a three.js beginner. I'm attempting to add a sphere to the scene, using position coordinates returned from a JavaScript get request.

A sphere created before the get request is rendered properly, but a sphere created and added to the scene in the callback function is not rendered - although if I debug and inspect the scene, both spheres exist as its children.

My code:

```
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius),
  sphereMaterial);
sphere.position.set(-20,-20,-20);
scene.add(sphere); // this sphere shows

sphere2 = sphere.clone();
sphere2.position.set(50,50,50); // testing initializing outside 

$.get("{% /graph %}",function(data,status){
  scene.add(sphere2); // this sphere does not show
});

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I tried initializing the second sphere inside and outside the callback, I've tried creating the new sphere instead of cloning, I'm not sure what else to try and I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery `get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) request is an asynchronous request. The callback function will not be called until after the render call. This means that the object will get added to the scene, but never drawn.

You will need to call the render function inside the `get` handler.

```
$.get("{% /graph %}",function(data,status){
  scene.add(sphere2);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Alternately, if you create a rendering loop for things like animation, this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was going to be something stupid :D